# Como iniciar un proyecto de Java con un JxTaskPane cerrado?

Tags: java, jframe

Tengo varios JxTaskPane en una aplicacion de java y pues quisiera saber como hacer que al momento de ejecutar el mismo los JxTaskPane esten cerrados

Ya lo resolví por si algun cristiano necesita.
JxTaskPane  tiene un método setCollapsed que recibe un boolean solo envien true al metodo al iniciar la aplicacion y listo xd

```
JxTaskPane.setCollapsed(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

¿Has probado a usar el método [setCollapsed](http://javadoc.geotoolkit.org/external/swingx/org/jdesktop/swingx/JXTaskPane.html#setCollapsed(boolean)) de cada JxTaskPane al inicio de tu aplicación?

Comment: Ahhh si cierto.. gracias men